# htaccess rewrite doesn't work properly on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, xampp

I'm restructuring a site now, and I'm testing it on localhost (xampp).

In the root directory there were a couple of .htm files, which were converted to .php.
However I'd like to keep the .htm extension for SEO reasons.
So I created a .htaccess file with this content:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.htm [L]
```

But when I try to access a page like this to test rewrite:
http://localhost/sitename/anything.php

I always get to
http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/sitename/anything.htm

which obviously produces a 403 error.

I have tried to change .htaccess options, but no success.
Rewrite module is enabled in Apache, so it is not the case.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just a comment. The extension won't make any difference to your website's SEO. The main reason you would mod rewrite for SEO is if you have lengthy, parameterised URLs or if you previously had html pages and you are making the content dynamic but don't want to go through the whole process of 301 redirecting your whole site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a RewriteBase directive i.e.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.htm [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect using the requested URI:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}.htm [R=301,L]
```

I tested it and it added ".htm" to all my php URIs test.php -> test.php.htm

No need for backreferences here.